# Extended VSAM allocation

Tags: mainframe, jcl, vsam

I have been tasked with a project that requires a VSAM file over the 4GB limit. I am trying to define an extended VSAM using IDCAM, but I cannot find an example or guide to help me. This is how I would define a regular VSAM:

```
//STEP1 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD*
 DEFINE CLUSTER                      - 
       (NAME(AA.AFILE.AV)            -      
        KEYS(10 0)                   -             
        RECSZ(1011 1011)             -         
        INDEXED                      -  
                                     -         
                                     -         
        CYL (50 50)                  -              
        VOL (* * * * * * * * * *)    -
        SHR (2 3)                    -
       )                             -
        DATA                         -
       (NAME(AA.AFILE.AV.DATA)       -      
        SHR (2 3) )                  -
        INDEX                        -
       (NAME(AA.AFILE.AV.INDEX)      -      
        SHR (2 3)                    -
       )  
/*
```

I was reading that there is an option of DSNTYPE=EXTREQ, but no matter where I place it, I get an error. Can someone show me an example of how to use IDCAMS to allocate an extended VSAM?

Comment: DSNTYPE is a DFSMS Data Class definition parameter, which is required for Extended Datasets. It is not part of the IDCAMS DEFINE. You will almost certainly need to talk to your storage management people. They will be able to tell you exactly what you need at your site.

Comment: @BillWoodger that makes sense, thanks

Comment: @BillWoodger it is also a JCL DD keyword. **SaggingRufus** extended VSAM has a lot of dependencies (DEFINE CLUSTER EATTR(OPT), which is the default for VSAM; SMS data class; JCL keywords; model data set; SVC 99 parms) to pass before it gets extended attributes. However, this may be one of those few rare times where creating a VSAM data set in JCL may work better than IDCAMS, as you can specify DSNTYPE=EXTREQ. I'm a bit rusty on the DD keywords required, but the fine JCL User's Guide and Reference, as well as DFSMS manuals, hopefully can provide some assistance.

Comment: added the answer that helped me below. It seems kind shady to accept my own answer, so ill just leave it unaccepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this answer for anyone who comes after me with the same question:

I talked to the storage guys at my site, and they were able to set up some sort of filter on the system. Now, every time we allocate these VSAMS (the way we allocated them in the past) they will be extended VSAMS by default. There were no JCL changes we needed to make.